# Switching between fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my app, i use a dual panel layout where each buttons on the left side replaces the fragments at the right side(Frame Layout).

The FragmentTransaction.replace() method actually removes the current one and add another fragment, so i need to create new instance everytime when switching between Fragments.

How can i save the fragment instance and replace?
Or is there anyway to switch between the fragments without replacing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `FragmentTransaction#show()` and `FragmentTransaction#hide()` methods?